# borderWidth on Android in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I don't understand why on Android the text is ON the border (not inside), when the borderWidth property of the Text element is greater than 1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsJCw.jpg)

```
const BoxScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Child #1</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Child #2</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Child #3</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'black',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  },
  textStyle: {
    borderWidth: 50,
    borderColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

Comment: can you explain your question properly? what actually do you need?

Comment: I can help you but please your question properly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have border for each of the child, you'll have to make them have their own view

```
const BoxScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
      <View style={styles.viewChild}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Child #1</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Child #2</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Child #3</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewChild: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'red',
  },
  textStyle: {

  }
});
```